# Getting file count while iterating through directories & folders

Tags: bash, shell

```
recursiveprint() {
#FILES_COUNT=0

cd $1
  for d in *; do
    if [ -d "$d" ]; then
       (recursiveprint "$d")
    fi
    if [ -f "$d" ]; then
       file_name=$(basename "$d")
        ((FILES_COUNT++))
        clear
        echo  "$file_name"
        echo "total count = $FILES_COUNT"
    fi
    done
}
recursiveprint ${START_DIR}
```

The issue is, once it goes through one folder, it sets the count back to zero before iterating through another folder. Altogether, I have 30 files in different folders, the count ends up being 6 i.e the number of files in the last folder it iterates through. Any tips on how to solving this?

Answer (score 5):

```
if [ -d "$d" ]; then
   (recursiveprint "$d")
fi
```

The parenthesis surrounding the line `(recursiveprint "$d")` run the function in a subshell. When the subshell starts, the value of `FILES_COUNT` is cloned, and changes made in the recursive call within the subshell don't take effect in the surrounding environment.

Without a subshell, it should work better, but then you need to manually go back to the parent directory when returning from an instance of the function. `cd ..` would do for the calls made within the function, but let's use a variable so we can go back to the original working directory, even if it's given as an absolute path.

```
recursiveprint() {
    local oldpwd=$PWD
    cd "$1"
    ...
        if [ -d "$d" ]; then
           recursiveprint "$d"          # no parenthesis here
        fi
    ...
    cd "$oldpwd"
}
```

Also note that `*` doesn't match filenames starting with a dot by default, use `shopt -s dotglob`, if you want it to.

Comment: My understanding of Bash is only decent so please do bear with me.Upon amending the script file, the $oldpwd is only echoing the last folder with the # of file(s) in it,not the total files in the whole directory (30). Here is the amended script file:

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env bash
START_DIR="/tmp/shakapaka"
#FILES_COUNT=0
recursiveprint() {
local oldpwd=$PWD
cd $1
  for d in *; do
    if [ -d "$d" ]; then
       (recursiveprint "$d")
    fi
    if [ -f "$d" ]; then

        #((++FILES_COUNT))
       file_name=$(basename "$d")
        clear
        echo  "$file_name"
        echo "total count = $oldpwd"
    fi
    done
}
recursiveprint ${START_DIR}

Comment: @Raphael, it's the parenthesis that start the subshell, you still have them in that snippet.

Comment: When I take off the parenthesis, it comes up with an error: fileshaka.sh: line 20: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
fileshaka.sh: line 20: `}'
[root@crap01 shakapaka]#

Comment: Currently have this: #!/usr/bin/env bash
START_DIR="/tmp/shakapaka"
#FILES_COUNT=0
recursiveprint{
local oldpwd=$PWD
cd $1
  for d in *; do
    if [ -d "$d" ]; then
       (recursiveprint "$d")
    fi
    if [ -f "$d" ]; then

        #((++FILES_COUNT))
       file_name=$(basename "$d")
        clear
        echo  "$file_name"
        echo "total count = $oldpwd"
    fi
    done
}
recursiveprint $START_DIR

Comment: @Raphael, no, the parenthesis in the function definition are required. It's the parenthesis you used when calling the function that starts the subshell. (in `(recursiveprint "$d")`, see the first code block in the answer). Compare something like `foo=1; ( foo=2 );  echo $foo` with and without parenthesis around the second assignment.

Answer (score 3):

Won't

`find /my/dir/ -type f | grep -c .`

work for you?

Answer (score 2):

```sh
find .// -type f | grep -c '^\.//'
```

will count all files reliably (even those that comprise newlines in their names).